# DiscordAPIError: While starting the bot

Tags: discord.js

Here's the API error:

```js
DiscordAPIError
    at RequestHandler.execute (/rbd/pnpm-volume/04d08e99-6e35-44ec-9f4c-98cf4b966f51/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5) {
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: '',
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot',
  code: undefined,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

I have no idea what any of this means or what I need to fix, it was working fine before, I didn't change any of the code :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error included the method 'GET', we know there was likely a failure requesting data from some part of the Discord API.
In the [Discord API Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro), the following is stated:

> - 403 responses are avoided by inspecting role or channel permissions and by not making requests that are restricted by such permissions

Your client may be attempting to do something that they don't have access to, e.g editing a role above their highest role, renaming a channel without sufficient guild permissions, etc.
Look through your code and see if you can find what's making it do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but apparently it just fixed by itself! But I'll mark it as an answer for anyone in the future~